# Contents of copied structure changes after temporary structure is `free` d

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

I'm making a simple database program to learn about structures and binary trees. I've created a global structure `Student` with 3 fields: first name, surname, age, and written a function to take 3 user inputs (stored as strings `in_fname`, `in_sname`, and int `in_age`, say) and place them into a temporary struct `new`, with the plan to copy them to the appropriate location of the main tree. After taking the user inputs for the first entry I have:

```
struct Student *new;
new = (Student *) malloc (sizeof(struct Student));
strcpy (new->fname, in_fname);
strcpy (new->sname, in_sname);
new->age = in_age;
new->left = new->right = NULL;
printf("Contents of new is '%s', '%s', '%d'.\n",new->fname, new->sname, new->age);

student_tree = new  /* wanting to copy the new student as the first entry in the tree*/
```

Now when I

```
print("Contents of structure is '%s', '%s', '%d'.\n",student_tree->fname, student_tree->sname, student_tree->age);
```

I get the correct entries, indicating the copy has worked, but when I

```
free(new)
print("Contents of structure is '%s', '%s', '%d'.\n",student_tree->fname, student_tree->sname, student_tree->age);
```

(thinking it was a temporary and I don't need it any more) when I  the first entry `fname` is always corrupted, containing junk.

Can someone explain what I'm missing? Don't necessarily want fixed code, just to understand why the contents of the structure in the tree change when the thing I copied it from disappears, and how I can copy it permanantly.

Many thanks,

W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `student_tree` and `new` are pointers. When you assign `new` to `student_tree`, there is no copying, it just makes `student_tree` point to the same memory. When you call `free(new)`, it reclaims the memory pointed to by `new`, which is also the memory `student_tree` points to, so it's understandably junk.

Here is some code that will do an actual copy:

```
struct Student* student_tree = malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
*student_tree = *new;
```

Here I am creating the pointer `student_tree`, allocating memory to hold the `struct Student`, and finally putting the contents of the memory pointed to by `new` in the memory pointed to by `student_tree`.

Answer (score 2):

Doing `free(now)` and then accessing `now` later is like turning off your engine and then wondering why your car does not accelerate anymore when you press the gas pedal.

Note that

```
student_tree = new
```

is **not** copying the contents where `new` is pointing, it is just assigning
another pointer to the location where `new` is pointing to. What you have here
is just 2 pointer that point to the same location. If you do `free(now)`, then
both pointers are pointing to freed memory and of course you cannot access the
memory with either one of the pointers (`new` nor `student_tree`).

If you want to free `new`, then you have to make a copy of the memory. This can
be done with `memcpy` like this:

```
struct Student copy;
memcpy(&copy, new, sizeof copy);
```

but depending on the structure itself (whether it contains pointer or arrays),
`memcpy` might not be the correct solution.

Right now it's difficult to give you a proper answer, because there are so much
information missing from you, like how `struct Person` looks like, how insert
functions look like, how you call them, etc.

Also

```
strcpy (new->fname, in_fname);
strcpy (new->sname, in_sname);
```

This may be dangerous, again you are not giving us enough information but if you
are not careful, you could overflow the buffers. I presume from your code that
`fname` and `sname` are both `char` arrays. In that case, I'd use `strncpy`
instead, because the real length of `in_fname` and `in_sname` might not be known
and/or might be larger than what `fname` and `sname` can hold. So in general the
more robust solution would be:

```
strncpy(new->fname, in_fname, sizeof new->fname);
new->fname[sizeof(new->fname) - 1] = '\0';

strncpy(new->sname, in_sname, sizeof new->sname);
new->sname[sizeof(new->sname) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Why `memcpy()`?  Why not structure assignment: `struct Student copy; copy = *new;`?  That will be at least as efficient as `memcpy()` unless the compiler writers completely screwed up — and is simpler.  The caveat about pointers inside the structure applies equally to assignment and `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've posted `new` is a pointer and does not contain the structure `Student`, but an address in memory to a `Student`. In C for the most part data can be stored in your program's stack memory or heap memory. Stack memory is managed, but becomes invalid as you exit a scope while heap memory is persistent throughout your program. `malloc()` allocates as much heap memory as you tell it to (in this case the enough for a `Student`) and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. Because the memory pointed to by `new` is persistent throughout your program you must manually free the memory with `free()`.

Important to understanding pointers is this line:

```
student_tree = new;
```

Without knowing what the type of `student_tree` it's hard to say what is happening, but let's assume that somewhere above there exists  the declaration `struct Student *student_tree;`. If that's the case then both variables are pointers allocated in your stack memory and `student_tree` is being assigned the value of `new` which is the address of the memory that you've allocated with `malloc()`.

Because both variables now point to the same memory, when that memory is freed neither pointer is pointing to valid memory.